# How to store a number as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have this code below that runs on a page, finds the element `input-optionXXX` where XXX is a 3 digit number that changes between 300 and 400, and clicks on it. I would like to store the numeric value that it finds on the page so that i can use that straight away in my other lines of code. Right now, in the section `print(i)`, it shows the correct value. I just need some way of storing that value.

```
for i in range(300, 400):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id(f'input-option{i}').click()
        print(i)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? If you can ``print(i)``, then ``i`` already stores the value.

Comment: Yeah that what i thought bu then when i try to put `i` into another line of code and print `i` then it will return the number 399 which is the highest value in the code `for i in range(300, 400):`

Comment: I updated the code please check it. I forgot to put the first line

Comment: So you only care about the last `i` that works?  Just assign it to another variable just before or after the `print`.

Comment: How can i assign it to another variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the intention of your code correctly, assigning the value to a new variable that is not i, and then breaking out of the for loop should do the trick. As long as you do not need to continue looking for "input-optionXXX", this should work, as break will only be reached if the try: succeeded which it would only do if it manages to find "input-optionXXX"

```
for i in range(300, 400):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id(f'input-option{i}').click()
        number = i
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        continue
```